a dm-crypt compatible aes-xts-plain64 decrypter
I need a portable decrypter that would be compatible with Linux dm-crypt aes-xts-plain64. While there is a plenty of aes implementations that would be compatible with aes-ecb, it looks I didn't find any C library that would provide something similar to aes_xts_plain64(uint8_t *buff, const uint8_t key[32], unsigned block_number).
I tried several AI prompts but it was delusional providing my an ad-hoc incorrect tweak algorithm.
I don't need anything very fast, because I need just to decrypt few megabytes, I don't need anything ported to a specific CPU, but I need to run it on very memory limited hardware.
I know there is an implementation is grub but it looks that it's as hard to extract from sources (grub/grub-core/disk/cryptodisk.c) as extracting from the kernel.
Perhaps there is a ready to use implementation? Just plain searching didn't reveal anything, but again searching didn't find grub sources, so perhaps there is a ready to use solution somewhere.
It is ok to have a library in non-C language, because I feel it's would be still easier to convert that to extract from linux or grub.

Looking at the GRUB sources, it looks like plain64 means the AES IV is the low 64 bits of the sector number... after that, it's probably just regular AES in XTS mode, and implementations for that should be easy to find?

No, plain64 is not xored before and after aes. It is also used in Galois field to hash. While it might be possible to extract it from grub, perhaps it's easier to find a solution somewhere.
